# How should I specify collectionView cell size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need my collection view cell to be sized depending on different conditions.

That is what I use now:

```swift
class CustomTabView: UIView {
...
func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> CGSize {
    calculateNeededItemSize()
}

func calculateNeededItemSize() -> CGSize {
    if tabsList.count > Constant.maximumFullscreenTabsCount {
        return UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: determineItemWidthForFullscreen(), height: frame.height)
    }
}

func determineItemWidthForFullscreen() -> CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(tabsList.count)
}
```

When I specify this line of code 'return UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize' with some test block it works fine. But otherwise I get a fatal error:

```
Thread 1: "UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: -setFrame: requires finite coordinates <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x138d079e0; index path: (0-0); frame = (0 0; 0 0)> - {{0, -inf}, {1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308}}"
```

Also, when I I indicate this line
'layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize'
without method `sizeForItemAt` it works but I just need my cell to have a different size depending on condition.

Collection View cell contains a label and it's width should be adjusted according to the text line:

```
    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: Constant.titleFontSize, weight: .medium)
        return label
    }()

    func setupView() {
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 15),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: -15),
            titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Comment: "height: frame.height"     whats this frame here ? i dont see you pass that variable to "calculateNeededItemSize" function

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa this is UIView class and its height frame (customTabView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)).

Comment: You are not giving enough information (code) for us to know what's going on here. You haven't even told us what the "fatal error" _is_. If you want help you need to be willing to be informative. But please note that the usual thing is to manipulate the cell's internal constraints and let it size itself automatically. It might be better, if you want help, to take a step back and just tell us what you are _really_ trying to accomplish in terms of overall layout.

Comment: @matt fixed the post

Comment: Yeah, well, like I said. This is quite a common crash when doing things this way; the problem is that you are being asked for information you do not have at the time the call is made. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes+setFrame%3A+requires+finite+coordinates for examples. As I say, if you would do things the normal way and just let the constraints size the cell, you'd end up with a coherent situation.

Comment: @matt there is no results in the link you provided. What exactly do you mean by "do things the normal way"?

Comment: I've already explained that in my earlier comment. — I don't know what you mean by "no results."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Compositional Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) instead of the FlowLayout you are using. FlowLayout requires calculating the precise size of each cell in your collection view whereas Compositional Layout can calculate the best fitting size if your cells are properly constrained. Moreover, you can adopt [the Composure library](https://blog.eclypse.io/create-forms-with-compositional-layout-in-uicollectionview-d89e6b6923c2) in your project to simplify Compositional Layout implementation even further. If you implement the recommended library, your implementation will be something like this:

```
import UIKit
import Composure

enum LayoutSections: Int, CaseIterable, DefinesCompositionalLayout {
    //list the number of sections in your layout. in this example there are 2 sections with
    //different layout requirements
    case section1
    case section2
    
    func layoutInfo(using layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> CompositionalLayoutOption {
        switch self {
        case .section1:
            //estimatedHeight does not need to be precise
            return .fullWidthDynamicHeight(estimatedHeight: 120)
        case .section2:
            return .fixedWidthDynamicHeight(fixedWidth: 180, estimatedHeight: 150)
        }
    }
}
```

then in your view controller, you would do this to perform the layout. Composure takes care of the rest.

```
import UIKit
import Composure

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //other code
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = generateCompositionalLayout(with: LayoutSections.allCases)
        //...
    }
    ...
}
```